# Counting backwards from 2000 in for loop C3

Tags: c#, decrement

```
for(i = 2000; i >= 0; i -= 40)                
{
Console.WriteLine("Your score is {0}", i);
}
```

i'm trying to count backwards from 2000 by 40 every time someone loops another for loop:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < random || i > random; i++)
{
count++;
Console.WriteLine("\r\nGuess [{0}]: Please enter a number:", i + 1);
string guessString = Console.ReadLine();
```

I'm trying to make a scoreboard so every time you don't guess a number correctly, it deducts 40 from 2000.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: What do you mean here "every time someone loops another for loop" ? The code doesn't make any sense. Please explain it and specify the question correctly so that we can help you.

Comment: I'm trying to make a scoreboard so every time you don't guess a number correctly, it deducts 40 from 2000.

Comment: Oh Ok. I see! Alright... and If they guess right, what happens?

Comment: Games over, here's your score: which would be 2000 - 40( -40 each loop it took to get the correct one)

Comment: What happens if the score hits 0 and you still didn't guess correctly?

Comment: Gave Over, you lost! Hah aha...

Comment: it won't. max is 50.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the variables you need are: the amount of guesses, the score, the value to find, and then in each iteration you need the user's input. This can be solved with a single loop.

Here's some pseudocode to show how you can approach this:

```
remainingGuesses = 50
score = 2000

while remainingGuesses > 0
    userInput = GetInput()
    if userInput == random
        break
    remainingGuesses = remainingGuesses - 1;
    score = score - 40

return score
```

You could otherwise go from attempt 0 to 49 and say `score = 2000 - 40 * attempts`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly from the comments above, you want to deduct 40 points every time someone guesses a number incorrectly.

You can have a variable that holds the score and initialize it with 2000 points and create a function that deducts 40 points each time someone guesses wrong.

```
int startingPoints = 2000;

public void DeductPoints() {
    startingPoints -= 40;
}
```

And then, you can do some if/else statements to do checks on the score and the corresponding output you want to show to the user.